# quarkus: reactive mutiny returns object Uni reference instead of string value

Tags: quarkus, mutiny

I'm getting this resource when I'm reaching my endpoint:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/hello
io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem@255ef91
```

This is my code:

```java
@Path("/hello")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GreetingResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Uni<String> hello() {
        return Uni.createFrom().item("item1");
    }
}
```

Those are my quarkus project dependencies:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-neo4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-mutiny</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of `quarkus.platform.version` in the `pom.xml`?

Comment: Also: could you check if the problem persists when the endpoint returns an `application/json` instead of `text/plain` (you may have to add the `quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson` dependency for this to work)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RESTEasy, and the `quarkus-resteasy` extension, don't know what `Uni` is and cannot serialize it properly.

If you can, I'd advice you to switch to `quarkus-resteasy-reactive` (and `quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson`) if you're using reactive types.

If you need the classic RESTEasy, add `quarkus-resteasy-mutiny` to your dependencies.

Comment: Another question, do I need to add `quarkus-resteasy` if I need to mix imperative and reactive paradigm? Is it enought importing `quarkus-reateasy-reactive` to mix imperative and reactive?

Comment: quarkus-reateasy-reactive is enough. If you add both, your build will fail. `quarkus-resteasy-reactive` is an entirely separate implementation of the same API.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that your resource returns content-type text.

```
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
```

To fix this you have to change it to:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

Full code:

```
@Path("/hello")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GreetingResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Uni<String> hello() {
        return Uni.createFrom().item("item1");
    }
}
```